# How to get socket data on first render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to make a real-time chat app using React.JS.
After the user has created the username, jump to: /home.
All connected users will be displayed in /home.

Here is the code I wrote (ShowUser.js):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Context from "../../context/Context";
import { useContextSelector } from "use-context-selector";

export default function ShowUsers() {

    const socket = useContextSelector(Context, item => item.socket)
    const [ alluser, setAlluser ] = useState([])

    const get_data = () => {
        socket.on("send_users", (users) => {
            setAlluser(users)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        get_data()
        console.log(alluser)
        return () => {
            socket.off("send_users")
        }
    })

    return (
        <div style={{ background: "white" }}>
            {alluser.length}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Server Side:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});

const users = [];

app.use(cors());

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    const id = socket.id;
    socket.on("create", (username, callback) => {
        //檢查user是否存在
        //存在 ? 提醒已存在 : 加入users && 將users給前端
        const existingUser = users.find((user) => user.username === username);

        if (existingUser) return callback("This username is been taken!");
        const user = { id, username };
        users.push(user);
        console.log(`${id} create ${username}`);

        io.emit("send_users", users);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        const id = socket.id;

        const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id);

        if (index !== -1) {
            users.splice(index, 1)[0];
        }

        console.log(`${id} leave`);
    });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3300, () => {
    console.log(`running in 3300`);
});
```

useEffect will be executed after return.
So {alluser.length} will be zero.
How can I solve this situation?
My English is not good.
Please forgive me.

Comment: but you are changing state also so as soon as the state changes react will re-render the component and `alluser.length` will show up

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have the same thought.
But it is true that it shows 0 on "/home".
I don't know why this happens.

Comment: You need to call `socket.on("send_data", ...);` *before* `io.emit("send_users", users);` runs server-side. You can simply copy the code that sends the users to a separate handler and request the users after the component has mounted.

Comment: @ChrisG 
I'm trying to understand what you mean by this sentence.
Sorry I need some time.
English is really difficult for me...

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'll try it this way: the current order in which things happen is: 1. client sends "create" 2a. user is created, pushed to array, server sends "send_users" 2b. client jumps to /home, starts listening for "send_users" (too late) 3. alluser remains []

Comment: The solution: in your server, add `socket.on("load_users", () => io.emit("send_users", users))` and in your client, send "load_users" to the server after calling `socket.on("send_data", ...);`

Comment: @ChrisG
Hi
Sorry for replying so late.
I have two things to tell you.
1. In the above Home.js I wrote "send_users" as "send_data". But this does not affect the program or the error occurs
2. The solution you proposed is useful. But when the user disconnects, the `alluser.length` on the page will not refresh.

Comment: @ChrisG Hello
I have solved the problem of disconnect.
Maybe it's because I've been bothered by this problem for a long time.
Made some undeserved mistakes.
Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Context from "../../context/Context";
import { useContextSelector } from "use-context-selector";

export default function ShowUsers() {
    const socket = useContextSelector(Context, (item) => item.socket);
    const [alluser, setAlluser] = useState([]);

    const get_data = () => {
        socket.emit("load_users");
        socket.on("send_users", (users) => {
            setAlluser(users);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        get_data();
        console.log(alluser);
    }, []);

    return <div style={{ background: "white" }}>{alluser.length}</div>;
}
```

Server Side:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});

const users = [];

app.use(cors());

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    const id = socket.id;
    socket.on("create", (username, callback) => {
        //檢查user是否存在
        //存在 ? 提醒已存在 : 加入users && 將users給前端
        const existingUser = users.find((user) => user.username === username);

        if (existingUser) return callback("This username is been taken!");
        const user = { id, username };
        users.push(user);
        console.log(`${id} create ${username}`);

        socket.on("load_users", () => {
            io.emit("send_users", users);
        });
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        const id = socket.id;

        const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id);

        if (index !== -1) {
            users.splice(index, 1)[0];
        }

        io.emit("send_users", users);
    });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3300, () => {
    console.log(`running in 3300`);
});
```

Make the following changes：

1. In Server Side add `socket.on("load_users" () => {...})`
2. In Client Side add `socket.emit("load_users")`